# How to solve: The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<dynamic>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I always get the error The argument type 'dynamic' cannot be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable' for the line json["geraete"].map((x) => RDevice.fromJson(x)), can someone help me?

```
factory Reservation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Reservation(*emphasized text*
        resNr: json['resNr'] as int,
        vbid: json['vbid'] as int,
        benutzer: json['benutzer'] as String,
        geraete:  List<RDevice>.from(**json["geraete"].map((x) => RDevice.fromJson(x))**),
          von: json['von'] as String,
          bis: json['bis'] as String,
        abgabe: json['abgabe'] as String,
          abholung: json['abholung'] as String,
          rdatum: json['rdatum'] as String,
          status: json['status'] as String,
          startTime: json['startTime'] as int, // slot nummer
          endTime: json['endTime'] as int,
      );
```

Here is the part from my RDevice class

```
factory RDevice.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => RDevice(
        id: json['id'] as int,
        resid: json['resid'] as int,
        deviceid: json['geraetid'] as int,
        description: json['bezeichnung'] as String,
      );
```

Comment: What does your JSON look like? *Is* 'geraete' an array, or is it something else?

Comment: "geraete" is an array with the attributes("id", "resid" "geraetid" and "bezeichnung")            here is an example of the json [{"resNr":11,"vbid":1,"benutzer":"JOHN.DOE","geraete":[{"id":3313,"resid":11,"geraetid":8,"bezeichnung":"Canon Camcorder"}],"von":"2022-06-23","bis":"2022-06-30","abgabe":"2022-06-10T18:41:05.001230","abholung":"","rdatum":"2022-06-07T09:56:00.903989","status":"ausgeliehen","startTime":0,"endTime":0},]

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it to

```
geraete:  List<RDevice>.from((json["geraete"] as List<Map<String, dynamic>>).map((x) => RDevice.fromJson(x))),
```

Comment: First, thanks for your help! But I still get an error "dynamic x"
The argument type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>'. In another project the line works, does it have something to do with the nullsafety?

Comment: @mascy check my edit. try that

Comment: VS Code does not show me an error but when I run it I get 
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast